# Write a csv file from a read_html origin

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im having troubles to export a html table (table 2) to a csv file. I have try using to_csv on the object pd.read_html but is not working

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import html.parser
import pandas as pd
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Juan Diego Bernate V/Documents/Python/Practica/APIs/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('https://www.ambito.com/contenidos/dolar-futuro.html')
res=driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
html=driver.page_source
soup= BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
tabla=soup.find_all('table')
tabla2=pd.read_html(html)

dia = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
ruta='C:/Users/Juan Diego Bernate V/'
nombre= ruta+ 'dolar_fut_rofex_2'+dia+'.csv'

tabla2.to_csv(nombre)
print (tabla2)
print (tabla)
```

This is the error message, I wrote all the code I used, before, I thought it was not relevant.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54234/devtools/browser/6a47dd26-ab5d-4318-b858-226180882e0f
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WSDinamicoRofex.py", line 34, in 
    tabla2.to_csv(nombre)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
Hope you can help me

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Show it please

Comment: Maybe the problem is the way you are specifying the path... but I need you to post the errors for helping you

Comment: Where did you get `df`? Did you really mean `tabla2.to_csv(nombre)`?

Comment: najeem looks to be correct. You’re wanting to take the read_html to to_csv. You stored stored read_html as table2, but then not using it for table2.to_csv(). Instead using df, which isnt defined as anything.

Comment: I updated the post, thank for your time

Answer (score -2):

I can't quite run your example, but try [`astropy`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/index.html). Something like this should do:

```
from astropy.io import ascii

# your code here

tbl = ascii.read(html_table, format='html')
```

this produces an `astropy` [`Table`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/index.html), which is very easy to manipulate and you could then save to another file using

```
ascii.write(tbl, 'table.csv', format='csv')
```

or, equivalently,

```
tbl.write('table.csv', format='ascii.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you @cristobal, I'll have that in mind, but I think pandas should be able to do that